# ODBC Oracle Connection error from MS Access upon reopen

Tags: oracle, odbc, ms-access-2010

I am connecting to Oracle tables via an MS Access DB (Access 2000 format) on Win 10 (likely same issue on Win 7). My 32-bit ODBC driver is configured and is functioning. This particular Access DB is used by 2 or 3 people on a network drive.

The issue is that whenever I reopen the Access DB, the connection is 'broken' and I must reenter my password each time.

This all started to miraculously appear when I got a new computer.

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I solved my own issue.

What worked for me is to delete all existing linked Oracle tables within the Access DB and then re-establish the linked tables.

When the Oracle table selection box pops up, select your tables and ensure the 'save password' is selected. Confirm settings with OK and a 'save password' dialog will pop up to warn you the "..password will not be encrypted before it is saved to the file...".  I was OK with this warning.  Now, each time I open the Access DB, I no longer need to reenter the credentials.